# Can I store custom context information with all miniprofiler entries?

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler

I'm using miniprofiler in my .NET MVC3 and MVC4 projects and SQL storage provider. I would like to harvest those logs for display in other systems...but need to store extra information with each log entry, such as the customer name, user id, report id, etc.

Is there a way to add custom fields and request-specific values to my current miniprofiler so the logs include those values in the SQL tables?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can archive this by implementing a custom class that derives from `DatabaseStorageBase`

The **DatabaseStorageBase** is located here: [DatabaseStorageBase.cs @ MiniProfiler GitHub](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/StackExchange.Profiling/Storage/DatabaseStorageBase.cs)

Nowadays, your are using the **SqlServerStorace**, correct ? The source for it is here: [SqlServerStorage.cs @ MiniProfiler GitHub](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/StackExchange.Profiling/Storage/SqlServerStorage.cs)

Just copy it, and change as your needs or you could even extend **SqlServerStorage** just overriding the **Save** (it's public), and implement custom **SaveTimings** (private) and **SaveClientTimings** (private) methods